# Encryption returns the same string as inputted original

Tags: python, list

This program will encrypt a message. It will take all the values with an even numbered index and place it into a list, and leave the odds in the first list. In the end it will give you a post Transposition encryption
message. 
Example: ababab becomes aaabbb

The above is what the program is supposed to do, however when I actually run the program the exact same string is given instead of the encrypted version.

```
crypt = [] # list to store original answers
original = raw_input("Enter your string: ") # prompts user for their desired string
crypt.append(original) # stores user answers in list crypt
crypt2 = [] # all the items with an even index from list crypt
x = 0

for a in crypt:
   if x % 2 == 1: # checks for oddness in the index value
      crypt2.append(a) # adds value associated with index to list crypt2
      crypt.remove(a) # removes value associated with index from list crypt
   x += 1

print crypt + crypt2
```

Is there an issue with the logic portion of my program?

Comment: While I don't know if it fixes your error, you should never change a list you are currently iterating over. Instead use a list comprehension.

Comment: Instead of looping over the *output* list, loop over the inputted string itself and append the character to the list you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did the loop:

```
for a in crypt
```

you run over the objects in the crypt list which has only 1 element and it is the string the user wrote.
change the program to this:

```
original = raw_input("Enter your string: ") # prompts user for their desired
crypt = [] # list to store original answers
crypt2 = [] # all the items with an even index from list crypt
x = 0
print original
for a in original:
    if x % 2 == 1: # checks for oddness in the index 
        crypt2.append(a) # adds value associated with index to list crypt2
    else:
        crypt.append(a)
    x += 1
print crypt + crypt2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a print statement to see how your loop is behaving, and you will find that `crypt` actually only contains only one entry.

When you do `crypt.append(original)` it puts the whole input as the single entry in crypt list. Then, when you do `for a in crypt`, a only becomes the entire user input once and then the loop terminates.

If you wanted to loop over the characters instead, use **crypt.extend** instead of `crypt.append`.

Answer (score 1):

```
new = ''.join([char for i, char in enumerate(original) if i % 2 == 0])
```

This may prove useful too.

Answer (score 1):

after `crypt.append(original)`, `crypt` is `['ababab']` instead of `['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']`. besides, you'd better not alter a list when you iterate it unless you know what you are doing. for your purpose, iterate `original` is enough.

```
crypt = []
original = raw_input("Enter your string: ") 
crypt = [c for c in original] # convert str to list
crypt2 = [] 
x = 0

for a in original:
   if x % 2 == 1: # checks for oddness in the index value
      crypt2.append(a) # adds value associated with index to list crypt2
      crypt.remove(a) # removes value associated with index from list crypt
   x += 1

print crypt + crypt2
```

OUTPUT:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'] 
# if you want 'aaabbb', using print ''.join(crypt + crypt2)
# this will give you 'aaabbb'
```

A simple way to do this:

```
>>> original = 'ababab'
>>> original[::2] + original[1::2]
'aaabbb'
>>>
```